# Can we call IBM worklight 7 adapter from WatchOS 2 extension?

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, watchos-2

Developing iPhone application with WatchOS 2 in IBM worklight 7 version. Can we call IBM Worklight 7 adapter from WatchOS 2 Extension?. It was working with WatchOS 1.

I found that IBM worklight 7 is depend on Cordova and Cordova have some support like AddressBook which use to get contacts from iPhone and its not support in WatchOS 2.

Answer (score 1):

IBM MFP 7.x adapters cannot be called from WatchOS 2. This is possible with IBM MFP 8.0.